# Adding stuff to the path integral (Faddeev-Popov method)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, brst

I'm wondering about the [Faddeev-Popov method](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Faddeev-Popov_ghosts) described in Peskin Schroeder and also on page 7 in [this link](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=KjURU6mnMMThywOT4YLYCg&url=http://www.win.tue.nl/~ygennip/documents/Faddeev-Popov.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNH3-R2sUNN_Vvsr41B9wPjqi3ZY1g&sig2=b3m-O1gXcQBGDKFyRqYqtw).

What gives them the right to simply add the Gaussian $\omega$ and thus introduce the $\xi$ parameter? It seems so arbitrary to me.

Are there any rigorous derivation of the [Faddeev-Popov method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost)?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v4): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always allowed to introduce a new integration variable as long as its not its already being summed over. This might be more clear in discrete form:
\begin{align} 
\int d x \, f (x) & \rightarrow  \Delta x\sum _i  \,f ( x _i ) \\ 
& = \big( N \Delta y\sum _j   g ( y _j ) \big)  \Delta x \sum _i  f ( x _i ) \\ 
\end{align} 
where $ N \Delta y\sum _j  g ( y _j ) = 1 $ (note that it is very important this doesn't depend on $x$). Then,
\begin{align} 
\int d x \, f (x)& \rightarrow N  \Delta x \Delta y \sum _{i,j} f ( x _i ) g ( y _j )  
\end{align}
The only difference with the Fadeev Poppov procedure is that now $ g ( y ) $ is also a function of a new unphysical parameter,$\xi$. In order to not change the value of the integral over $ f (x) $, the constant $ N $ needs to also change with $ \xi $.

Comment: You make sense, PS didn't.