# The Faddeev-Popov generating functional and its independence on the gauge-fixing function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, gauge

A technical question on the Faddeev-Popov procedure (P&S Chapter 9). P&S introduce the functional integral, which is equal to one and then they choose the gauge-fixing function $G(A)$ to be equal to
$$G(A)=\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}(x)-\omega(x)\tag {9.55}$$
which is totally fine with me. They are allowed to do so, I guess (although some thoughts on their motivation could be useful if there are any).

The resulting expression for the generating functional is proportional to
$$Z\sim\int\mathcal{D}Ae^{iS[A]}\delta(\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}-\omega).$$
Then, they make the claim that the generating functional is independent of the newly introduced scalar function $\omega(x)$ and then multiply by a normalization constant with an integral, which is again understandable, if and only iff the generating functional is indeed independent of $\omega(x)$. I have seen the [relevant post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101350/)  asking why are they allowed to do that, but this is not my question.

My question is: can we somewhow show that the generating functional is independent of the scalar function $\omega(x)$? I was thinking something like showing that its functional derivative w.r.t. the latter scalar function is zero, or something like that. Namely, that
$$\frac{\delta Z}{\delta \omega}=0.$$
Also, would any form of $G(A)$'s dependence on $\omega(x)$ reproduce a generating functional that is independent of the latter?

Comment: You said yourself that the path integral they introduce equals 1, and 1 does not depend on $\omega$. The fact we can use $\omega$ comes from this equality, which is just a change of coordinate.

Comment: You have to integrate out $\omega(x)$. Otherwise, it depends on $\omega(x)$. To do so, you insert $e^{i\int d^{4}x\omega^{2}}$ into the functional integrand, and then integrate out the $\omega$ field be performing a Gaussian functional integral $\int\mathcal{D}\omega$.

Comment: Would it help you to write $G(A,\omega)$, instead, and note $\partial G/\partial  \alpha$ doesn't depend on ω ?

Comment: Hi all and thanks for the reply. Okay, I guess that by reverse engineering the derivation, one can show that the generating functional is indeed independent of $\omega(x)$, but is there a way of attacking the problem from the final expression (like demonstrating that the functional derivative wrt $\omega(x)$ vanishes?)?

Comment: @LibertarianFeudalistBot I think that even before integrating out $\omega(x)$ the generating functional is independent on $\omega$, no??

Comment: @CosmasZachos maybe, but there still exists an $\omega(x)$ term in the delta functional and I would like to see/understand/explain why this term (in $\delta$) does not yield any dependence of the generating functional on it!

Comment: @CosmasZachos oh I guess you mean to define $G$ s.t. it does not exhibit $\omega$ dependence and only choose such functions by definition... If so, yes, this is considerably better, but still, what of the $\delta$ functional argument $\omega(x)$... How does $Z$ not depend on this $\omega$?

Comment: I think you are getting caught up in notation. Illustrate everything with the trivial case of one point *x*, so three plain integrals, and some notional gauge invariance leaving S(A) unchanged.  It should be straightforward.

Comment: PS an elegant plain-variables toy model relying on rotational invariance instead of shift invariance  I proposed above is on pp 190-192 of George Sterman's Introduction to QFT.

Comment: I also have a trouble here, why in the paragraph below (9.55), the book said "The functional determinant is the same as in Lorentz gauge, $\operatorname{det}\left(\delta G\left(A^\alpha\right) / \delta \alpha\right)=\operatorname{det}\left(\partial^2 / e\right)$". Why the determinant in this general case equal to that with Lorentz gauge? Could you please explain for me?

Comment: Hi @Daren. Do you mean that you have difficulty in convincing yourself that $\text{det}(\delta G(A^a)\delta \alpha)=\text{det}(\partial^2/e)$??

Comment: @schris38 Hello! I can convince myself that for Lorentz gauge, $\text{det}(\delta G(A^a)\delta \alpha)=\text{det}(\partial^2/e)
$. I just thinking if this determinant is gauge invariant, since the book said for a general $\omega(x)$, still satisfy this. However, today I checked Srednicki's book, and basically understand that. Previously I may lost on Peskin's logic. If you have any comment, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general fact about gauge theories, not just E&M.

1. In a nutshell the independence of the gauge-fixing function in the path integral/partition function $Z$ is a generalization of the fact that
   $$ \int_{\Omega}\! d^nx ~\left|\det\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \right|\delta^n(f(x))~=~1 $$
   as long as the [pre](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html)-[image](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pre-Image.html) $f^{-1}(\{\vec{0}\})$ of the smooth function $f: \Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$
   is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)).
2. Alternatively, the independence of the gauge-fixing function in $Z$ follows from that the Faddeev-Popov (FP) term plus the gauge-fixing (GF) term $S_{FP}+S_{GF}$ in the gauge-fixed action is BRST-exact. This is e.g. explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39096/2451).
3. For more general gauge theories this can be proven via the [Batalin-Vilkovisky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) (BV) formalism.

References:

1. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; eq. (9.55).
2. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Chapter 71. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).
3. G. Sterman, *An Intro to QFT,* 1993; p. 190-192. (Hat tip:
   [Cosmas Zachos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos)).