# Proving that the Faddeev-Popov path integral is independent of the gauge choice?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, yang-mills, gauge

I know that the Faddeev-Popov path integral is *gauge invariant*. But how does one show that
\begin{equation}
I = \int \mathcal{D}\mathcal{A}_\mu \bigg|\frac{\delta\mathcal{G}}{\delta{\omega}}\bigg|\delta(\mathcal{G})  \exp(- S_\text{YM}[A_\mu])
\end{equation}
is independent of the gauge choice $\mathcal{G}$? Here $\omega$ is the infinitesimal gauge parameter and $S_\text{YM}$ is the Euclidean Yang-Mills action. I came across this while reading Ramond's *Field Theory: A Modern Primer* but haven't found the explicit proof and I am unable to do. This is the first time I am seeing this material.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715195/2451