# Calculating a Gaussian-like path integrals with Grassmann variables and real variables

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, grassmann-numbers, ghosts

I want to compute the following path integral
$$Z[w] = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int d^n x \: \prod_{i=1}^{n}d\overline{\theta}_id\theta \: \exp{\left(-\overline{\theta}_i \partial_j w_i(x)\theta_j -\frac{1}{2}w_i(x)w_i(x)\right)}.\tag{1}$$ Here $w_i(x)$ are functions of the $n$ real variables $x_i$ and $\theta_i$ and $\overline{\theta}_i$ are $n$ independent Grassmann variables.

The first step seems easy: computation of the $\theta$ and $\overline{\theta}$ integrals give
$$Z[w] = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int d^n x \: \det(\partial_j w_i(x)) \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}w_i(x)w_i(x)\right)}.\tag{2}$$

From here, I tried using that $$\det(\partial_j w_i (x)) = \det\left(\partial_j w_i \left(\frac{d}{db}\right)\right) \exp\left(b_i x_i\right)\bigg\vert_{b=0}.$$ But I don't seem to be able to apply this step.

Comment: Is this from some reference? Which page? Which context?

Comment: @Qmechanic not specifically, just a small problem I wanted to solve

Answer (score 0):

1. This resembles the Faddeev-Popov (FP) construction, where $\theta^i,\bar{\theta}_j$ are the [FP ghost & antighost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost), respectively. In this answer we will assume that this is indeed the intention, possibly tweaking OP's coefficients to simplify and make it work.
2. The point is that OP's partition function $Z[w]$ then does not depend on the gauge-fixing function $w^j$ as long as the FP determinant $\det(\partial_i w^j)$ is non-zero and the $x$-integral is convergent, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/715195/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. A simple gauge choice is $w^j(x)=x^j$. Then the FP determinant becomes 1 and the $x$-integral becomes Gaussian.
4. It is perhaps easiest to see the independence of the gauge-fixing choice $w$ in the [BRST formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_quantization)$^1$
   $$ Z[w] ~=~ \int \! d^n x ~d^n \theta ~d^n\bar{\theta} ~d^nB~e^{iS} ,\tag{A} $$
   where we have introduced a Lautrup-Nakanishi (LN) auxiliary field $B$. The underlying "gauge" symmetry is $x$-translations. The BRST transformations are $$\begin{align} 
   {\bf s}x^i~=~&\theta^i, \cr
   {\bf s}\theta^i~=~&0, \cr 
   {\bf s}\bar{\theta}_i~=~&-B_i, \cr
   {\bf s}B_i~=~&0. \end{align}\tag{B}$$
   The action is BRST-exact
   $$\begin{align} S~=~~~&-{\bf s}\psi \cr
   ~\stackrel{(B)+(D)}{=}&~ \bar{\theta}_i \partial_j w^i \theta^j+B_i\left(\frac{\xi}{2}B_i+w^i\right) \cr
   ~\stackrel{\text{int. out} B}{\longrightarrow}&~~~\bar{\theta}_i \partial_j w^i \theta^j-\frac{w^iw^i}{2\xi},\end{align}\tag{C}$$
   where
   $$\psi ~=~ \bar{\theta}_i \left(\frac{\xi}{2}B_i+w^i\right)\tag{D}$$
   is the gauge-fixing fermion. One can now show that $Z[w]$ does not depend on $\psi$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39096/2451). $\Box$

--

$^1$ Various $i\epsilon$ prescriptions are implicitly assumed when needed for convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is there a way to further solve this integral? Looking online I only seem to find explanations *why* the determinant is introduced, not how we can compute it further

Comment: Looking online where? Which page?

Comment: Ok, that already brings me a big step closer! Is there a way to prove that it is independent of the gauge fixing function $w_i$? Or how can I compute the $x_i$ integrals further?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Again, thanks for the updated answer. I am however still confused on the integral. I get that it is independent of $w$, that you have shown in detail,  but I'm wondering if there is an explicit solution to this integral.

Comment: I also just now see your first comment; I'm looking at for example Peskin and Schroeder or the Osborn notes.